# Data is not populating in ListView

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am working on a screen in which i want to show data from the SQlite table.
While debugging what can i see is, data is coming in adapter but not populating in listview when it comes to listView.setAdapter(adapter). (I am using custom adapter, custom list item)

Any error is also not showing up.

Please help. I am posting my code below.

place_list_item :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/serial_number_textview_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/common_signin_btn_default_background"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/duration_textview_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textColor="@color/common_signin_btn_default_background"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/distance_textview_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textColor="@color/common_signin_btn_default_background"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

trip_history_screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#dbeaf8"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1.0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/heading_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_label_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Trip Histroy"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titles_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/serial_number_title_textview_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="No."
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration_title_textview_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Duration"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distance_title_textview_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Distance"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/trip_history_listview_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titles_layout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@drawable/listview_devider_dockets"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.RareMediaCompany.MuditaMileage.DataClasses.ListData;
import com.RareMediaCompany.MuditaMileage.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by SANGEETA on 17-08-2015.
 */
public class TripHistoryDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    private Typeface typeface;
    Context mContext;
    int resource;
//public TripHistoryDataAdapter(Context context, int resource, Typeface typeface) {
//    this.mContext = context;
//    this.resource = resource;
//    this.typeface = typeface;
//
//    // super(context, resource);
//}

    public TripHistoryDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    static class DataHandler {
        TextView number;
        TextView duration;
        TextView distanceCovered;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;
        row = convertView;
        DataHandler handler;
        Log.i("LstAdapter", "Inside getView");
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_list_item, parent, false);
            handler = new DataHandler();
            handler.number = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.serial_number_textview_id);
            handler.duration = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.duration_textview_id);
            handler.distanceCovered = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.distance_textview_id);
            row.setTag(handler);
        } else {
            handler = (DataHandler) row.getTag();
        }

        ListData historyDataProvider;
        historyDataProvider = (ListData) this.getItem(position);
        handler.number.setText(historyDataProvider.getNumber());
        handler.duration.setText(historyDataProvider.getTime());
        handler.distanceCovered.setText(historyDataProvider.getDistance());
        return row;
    }
}
```

fragment:

```
public class TripHistoryFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
//    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
//    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private MyDbHelper helper;
    private ListView listView;
    private TextView serialNumberTitle, timeTitle, distanceCoveredTitle;
    private TextView headerTextView;
    private List<ListData> dataList;
    private TripHistoryDataAdapter adapter;
    private Typeface typeface;
    private GetDataTask getDataTaskObj;
    // private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;


    public TripHistoryFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trip_history_screen, container, false);
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
                "fonts/AvantGarde.ttf");
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.trip_history_listview_id);
        serialNumberTitle = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.serial_number_title_textview_id);
        timeTitle = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.duration_title_textview_id);
        distanceCoveredTitle = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.distance_title_textview_id);
        headerTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.header_label_id);
        adapter = new TripHistoryDataAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.place_list_item);
        serialNumberTitle.setTypeface(typeface);
        timeTitle.setTypeface(typeface);
        distanceCoveredTitle.setTypeface(typeface);
        headerTextView.setTypeface(typeface);
        getDataTaskObj = new GetDataTask(getActivity());
     //   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            // allows task to run parallely
            getDataTaskObj.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,
                    (Void[]) null);
        } else {
            getDataTaskObj.execute();
        }
        return rootView;
    }


    public class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        Context context;
        Dialog dialog;

        // ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public GetDataTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;

            dialog = Utils.showValidationDialog(context, "Loading ...",
                    "Please wait ", false);

           // listDataArr = new ArrayList<ListData>();
        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            helper = new MyDbHelper(getActivity());

            Cursor cursor = helper.getAllLocationSavedCursor();
            //String myHexColor = "#CC2233";
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
                    String duration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("UnixTimeStamp"));
                    String distance = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("distance"));

                    adapter.add(new ListData(number, duration, distance));


                    //list.add(map);


                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                cursor.close();
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            if (adapter != null && !adapter.isEmpty()) {
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Running trip data is here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No History Found!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly let me know if anyone find something or if any more information is required.

Comment: did you try `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in your `onPostExecute()` method ?

Comment: first store the complete data to an arraylist and then pass the list to the adapter class via constructor. So initialize the adapter class in onPostExecute() method. make appropriate changes in Adapter class.

Comment: no no no, **don't use** any `ArrayAdapter`, your data model is sqlite db based so use `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead

Comment: Ya i have tried that method(First store the complete data to an arraylist and then pass the list to the adapter class via constructor. So initialize the adapter class in onPostExecute() method. make appropriate changes in Adapter class) also. but data is not showing up on the screen.

Comment: i tried adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in my onPostExecute() method also.. but nothing seems to be working

Comment: I try simpleCursorAdapter and let you know @pskink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Linear layout of trip_history_Screen.xml . Use this

```
 <LinearLayout
>         android:id="@+id/titles_layout"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/heading_layout"
>         android:orientation="horizontal"
>         android:weightSum="1.0">
```

Instead of this :

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titles_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0">
```